# Malformed buttons with SproutCore

Tags: javascript, gridview, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

This week I started learning SproutCore. I quite like the framework, but hate the absence of learning material. After going through most of the guides I decided to learn by trying to build something. I wrote a little GridView with buttons in it, but the buttons seem to be distorted, there are labelless blue copies under each button, and a couple of pink lines. What is this? Why is this? How do I get rid of it?

Relevant code:

```
buttons: SC.GridView.design({
  layout: { centerX: 0, top: 40, width: 300, height: 120 },
  columnWidth: 120,
  rowHeight: 58,
  contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Calculator.buttons'),
  exampleView: SC.ButtonView.extend({
    titleBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('.content')
  })
})
```

And:

```
Calculator.buttons = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 + - / x ='.w()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons and many of the other styled widgets have specific heights defined by the theme.  Set controlSize and the height of the button (rowHeight in the GridView in your case) to match one of the following:

- `SC.SMALL_CONTROL_SIZE`: 18px
- `SC.REGULAR_CONTROL_SIZE`: 24px
- `SC.HUGE_CONTROL_SIZE`: 30px
- `SC.JUMBO_CONTROL_SIZE`: 44px

For example:

```
buttons: SC.GridView.design({
  layout: { centerX: 0, top: 40, width: 300, height: 120 },
  columnWidth: 120,
  rowHeight: 44,
  contentBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('Calculator.buttons'),
  exampleView: SC.ButtonView.extend({
    titleBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('.content'),
    controlSize: SC.JUMBO_CONTROL_SIZE
  })
})
```

All of the images used in the theme are sprited into just a few master files, and CSS is used to choose which part of the tiled image to display.  What you are seeing is the graphic "overflowing" and displaying parts of images intended for other uses.  Does that make enough sense?

Comment: Brilliant! I'm not on my desktop now so I can't test it now, but it makes sense.

Comment: Good explanation John. Addendum: the pink lines are a developer-mode thing intended to make it really obvious when sprites aren't fitting correctly. The pink turns transparent when you build for production, though of course the goal is to have the sprites and the divs matching up by then!

Comment: @Dave Thanks! And to you and John Laxson: you seem to know quite a lot about SproutCore. Where did you learn this? I could not find even a remotely complete tutorial.

Comment: @11684 Some of the core team is spending a lot of effort right now to improve the guides, but a lot of SproutCore is presently black magic.  You just have to keep banging on it and you'll start to pick up on the mojo (the irc channel is a great resource), but the learning curve is not a shallow one.

Comment: I just checked the source and found two more sizes: `SC.LARGE_CONTROL_SIZE` and `SC.TINY_CONTROL_SIZE`. Where can I find the corresponding heights?