# Graphic view with sproutcore

Tags: sproutcore

I'm starting with sproutcore and todos [tutorial](http://guides.sproutcore.com/getting_started_3.html). My output is on picture below

[image]

I'm using chromium browser (linux). Sproutcore theme doesn't support this browser?
Or how can I fixed it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Buildfile, try to add `:use_sprites => false`.

Here is an example:

```
config :your_app,  
  :title => 'Your app', 
  :theme => 'sproutcore/ace',
  :use_sprites => false
```

I think it's because of a bug with abbot when it combines images.

And don't forget to reload sc_server ;-)

Comment: I agree with Nicolas, although, I have seen this happen randomly as well. You may want to first try deleting everything in the `tmp` directory and then restarting `sc-server` as sometimes the sprites can just get messed up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And do you know, where all the parameters possible to write to Buildfile are? I am not able to find them anywhere.

Comment: Disabling sprites will hurt the performance of your app, and it's not recommended. @TopherFangio is right – deleting the tmp folder and restarting sc-server is likely to fix part of your problem; the other part is likely due to having views larger than their sprites (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776835/malformed-buttons-with-sproutcore).)

Comment: As for buildfile options, I don't know if they're documented anywhere, but you can get a good look at what's available in the "default" buildfile located [here](https://github.com/sproutcore/abbot/blob/master/lib/Buildfile).

Comment: Here is a link to the current default Buildfile: https://github.com/sproutcore/abbot/blob/master/lib/Buildfile